# Unable to create an event for calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-apps

I am trying to create events dynamically based on some data. I was able to achieve this using the calendarApp. Now, I want to add a room to the event as well when the event is created. 
For that, I am trying to create an event for the calendar of that particular meeting room. I get the calendar of the meeting room using

```
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
```

However, I am unable to create an event for it. The above line is able to retrieve the calendar(its not null). However, when I try to add an event to it via calendar.createEvent it gives me an error saying 'Action not allowed'. I have subscribed to the above calendar. I have also tried using `Calendar.Calendars.get(calendarId);` to retrieve the calendar and `Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);` to add an event to it. However, the result is the same. What am I missing? I do not have admin rights to this room's calendar. Could that be the reason? If yes then how do I solve it?

Comment: are you the calendar owner?

Comment: no I am not the owner of the calendar but I have subscribed to it. I am able to fetch the calendar, however I am not able to add events to it.

Comment: subscribing means read only. how do you expect to create events?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. So does that mean I would not be able to add rooms to a meeting invite if I am not the owner of that meeting room calendar? When I go to calendar.google.com I am able to add a meeting room to any calendar event that I am creating. Is that not possible via appscript?

Comment: look at event guest modify permissions

Comment: ok thanks Zig I see in my settings it says "calendars I can only view". So yes you are right. Is there any way I can book a meeting room from my script like I am able to in google calendar?

Comment: you need to have write permission to the calendar or to the individual event.

Comment: I think you may be referring to resource calendars when you say 'meeting rooms'. You can programmatically add resource calendars to an event in your own calendar in the same way you add a guest, using the email address of that resource. Be aware that resources can decline the event (if they are already booked).

Comment: yes thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton Zig :)

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it by subscribing to the calendar resource I want to book via the calendar settings for the mail id I am going to be using and then adding the resource's mail id as a guest in my invite. Thank you Zig for your help!